# MS word 2016 Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA but I have a word 2016 template and it has the following sections:

```
Base Amount:    $   

Service Fee:    $       

Sales Tax %     $           
Other tax %:    $               
Tax 2     %:    $
```

My goal is if an amount is missing from any of the lines, then delete that line.

I tried recording the macro and then making changes but no luck.

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim i As Long
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Len(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text) = 2 Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code and people will see if they spot something.

Comment: Sub TEST()


Dim i As Long
With Selection.Tables(1)
For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If Len(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text) = 2 Then
.Rows(i).Delete
End If
Next i
End With

End Sub

Comment: Your code works fine for me - assuming your cell is 'empty' except for the two ascii characters 13 & 7; and that you have only one table. Are you certain you are executing the code?

Comment: The only problem is that it deletes all Empty lines, where as I am only interested in deleting the ones above. Or if I can use a bookmark of the $ dollar sign- delete the row if the 5 spaces next to the dollar sign are empty. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've added :

- the function `Trim` to remove useless spaces, so that you'll only have data left
- changed the `=` to `<=`

Code :

```
Sub TEST()
    Dim i As Integer
    With Selection.Tables(1)
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Len(Trim(.Cell(i, 2).Range.Text)) <= 2 Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With 'Selection.Tables(1)
End Sub
```