# MS Word VBA to delete empty lines

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA Macros but I have a word 2016 template and it has the following sections:

```
Base Amount: $ 
Service Fee: $ 
Sales Tax % $
Other tax %: $
Tax 2 %: $
```

My goal is if an amount is missing from any of the lines, then delete that line. I tried recording the macro and then making changes but no luck.

[image: Image of Word table]

Comment: It is disappointing that you did not include any useful information gained from your duplicate post yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053248/ms-word-2016-macro

People will still want to see the code, people will still need to know the other details you provided!  You need to understand that more info is better than less!   BTW, your code worked yesterday, but you wanted something you had not shared.

Comment: Wayne, Thanks for response. I had replied to your comment yesterday, but I guess you missed my comment.

Comment: What does "...deleting the ones above..." actually mean? All above? Only one above? Above what? Any empty cell, or multiple empty cells on the same row? Does an empty cell contain the $? Please explain EXACTLY what the problem is...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wayne.. I should have been more clear. I meant the ones I listed in my questions (above in this forum). What I really need is that if let say base amount: $ Blank then delete that line from the template  Base Amount: $ . Thanks!

Base Amount: $ 
Service Fee: $ 
Sales Tax % $
Other tax %: $
Tax 2 %: $

Comment: Delete something from the template or delete the actual row of data from the table in Word??

Comment: The line has the following : Service Fee: $ __amount would be here___. If there is no amount populated in this line then delete the entire line: Service Fee: $. Thanks!

Comment: Delete the line from the template.. I really appreciate you taking the time to help on this.. Thank you

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a template and a Word document? The template contains formatting, fields, etc. to be used to fill in information and create a document. The template usually remains static while the document can change often as data is added. I really believe you mean to delete from the document. If not, wow, please explain why you need to delete from the template.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the merged document.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:  Below is a modified version of your code that will spin thru all rows of a table (in MS-Word) and delete every row that contains only a '$' in column 3 and column 4 is empty.

```
Option Explicit

' This subroutine will spin thru all rows of data in a table in MS-Word (except the first row, which is the header).
' If column 3 contains only a '$' AND column 4 is empty, the row will be deleted.
' All rows with only the '$' in column 3 and empty cell 4 will be deleted.

Sub TEST()
Dim i       As Long
'Dim char    As String

    With Selection.Tables(1)
        For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            'char = .Cell(i, 3).Range.Text
            'Debug.Print Asc(Mid(char, 1, 1)) & vbTab & Asc(Mid(char, 2, 1)) '& vbTab & Asc(Mid(char, 3, 1))
            'Debug.Print ">" & .Cell(i, 2).Range.Text & "<"
            If Len(.Cell(i, 4).Range.Text) = 2 And Left(.Cell(i, 3).Range.Text, 1) = "$" Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for asking too many questions. I took the code and I need a tweak. I just realized that the value is in cell 4 and the dollar sign is in Cell 3. How should Include that in your code.. Logic : If Cell 3 is a dollar sign and Cell 4 is Empty then delete the whole line from the template.  Thank you so much for your help. you have no idea how this will help me.. Jeff!

Comment: Thanks one more time. For some reason it failed it says run time error 5941 "the requested member of the collection does not exist.". I truly appreciate your help. you don't have to bother with it. I will try to play with it later. Thank you so much.. Jeff Watson.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your table? You said you have at least 4 columns!! Adjust the code to reflect the actual number of columns.....

Comment: I actually inherited this from another person, but It looks like it has 5 columns. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help with this. The exact error you received can be duplicated in my test by having references to columns that don't exist. And to say 'it looks like it has 5 columns' is unacceptable. Accuracy is simple and required... just count them!

Comment: Sorry, it is 5 columns. Thanks!

Comment: Wayne, I added an image of the table in the question. Thank you!

Comment: Please post a link to your actual document and the latest code. I am spending way too much time trying to assist you and it seems the 'facts' keep changing (col 2 vs col 3? template vs document?) Yes, I could modify my code so it tests for every known possibility, and gives you a message if your column count is wrong or if you have no table, but that is not going to happen.

Comment: Wayne: Thanks for your help. You are right, this is taking more time than expected. I truly appreciate your assistance. I will just give up and drop it here. Thanks!